# Haskell cabal include static library

Tags: haskell, cabal, ffi

I have an embarrassingly simple question.

I am trying to use an archive library (call it `mylib.a`) with a large'ish C project (compiled with GHC's copy of MinGW).

From the top level I have:

```
./project.cabal
./src/...haskell..code...
./cbits/interface.c (simplifies access to `lib.a`)
./include/mylib.h
./lib/mylib.a      <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< not sure where to put this or how to reference it
```

The `project.cabal` has both

```
c-sources:           cbits/interface.c
include-dirs:        include
```

The `extra-lib-dirs` seems to want an absolute path (directory).

How does one solve this?

Comment: Linking in pre-compiled code is not really an ideal use case for cabal. You can do it, for example the intel-aes package has pre-compiled code for a few platforms distributed as `extra-source-files` then links those using cabal hooks from a `build-type: Custom` and customized `Setup.hs`.

Comment: Can you try `extra-libraries: mylib`? You need to add the proper paths to `extra-{lib/incude}-dirs`, and if you need custom linker options (e.g.) you can use `ghc-options: -optl <linker option>`. Unless you are using a makefile to build (or some other not-cabal build tool) you can probably get away without having to write a `Custom` build script.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this initially.  It yields the usual `* Missing C library: mylib` (during the `configure` step)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is from here https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4677

I suppose your archive is name `libmylib.a`, then add this in your cabal file

```
ghc-Options: -pgml gcc "-optl-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition" "-optl-Wl,--whole-archive" "-optl-Wl,-Bstatic" "-optl-Wl,-lmylib" "-optl-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-optl-Wl,--no-whole-archive"
```

you might also need to specify the gcc option `-L` to specify the archive path